# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Titanium

Tags: clang, linker-errors, titanium-modules

I got the following error, when loading Titanium module:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/goodlogics/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1379, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr,kroll_coverage)],False)
  File "/Users/goodlogics/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1286, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/goodlogics/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions in the section in the IOS module guide on adding new Frameworks?

[iOSModuleDevelopmentGuide Adding Special Compiler Directives](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide#iOSModuleDevelopmentGuide-AddingSpecialCompilerDirectives)